# Yesod Persistent - How to not migrate some Entities

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have an Entity which represents a view, and I would like to know if there is a way to simply mark it to not be migrated along with the other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `share` block for your models, don't use the `mkMigrate` function. For example,

```
share [ mkPersist sqlSettings
      , mkMigrate "migrateAllStatisticsModels"
      ] [persistLowerCase|
```

should be

```
share [ mkPersist sqlSettings
      ] [persistLowerCase|
```

You might need to use more than 1 `share` block to achieve this.

Comment: You answer was exactly what I was looking for, you also could have advised that those `share` cannot be in the same module, I discovered it because I got an error with the following message part `... must be imported, not defined locally`.